# Access Prodigy UI in Kubernetes Pod

Tags: python-3.x, azure, kubernetes, prodigy

I am attempting to create a service for creating training datasets using the Prodigy UI tool. I would like to do this using a Kubernetes cluster which is running in Azure cloud. My Prodigy UI should be reachable on 0.0.0.0:8880 (on the container).

As such, I created a deployment as follows:

```
kind: Deployment
  apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
  metadata:
    name: prodigy-dply
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: prodigy_pod
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: prodigy_pod
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: prodigy-sentiment
          image: bdsdev.azurecr.io/prodigy
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: ["/bin/bash"]
          args: ["-c", "prodigy spacy textapi -F training_recipe.py"]
          ports:
          - name: prodigyport
            containerPort: 8880
```

This should (should being the operative word here) expose that 8880 port at the pod level aliased as `prodigyport`

Following that, I have created a `Service` as below:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: prodigy-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: prodigy_pod
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: prodigyport
```

At this point, when I run the associated `kubectl create -f <deployment>.yaml` and `kubectl create -f <service>.yaml`, I get an `ExternalIP` and associated Port: `10.*.*.*:34672`.

This is not reachable by browser, and I'm assuming I have a misunderstanding of how my browser would interact with this Service, Pod, and the underlying Container. What am I missing here?

Note: I am willing to accept that kubernetes may not be the tool for the job here, it seems enticing because of the ease of scalability and updating images to reflect more recent configurations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find public IP address(LoadBalancer Ingress) with this command:

```
kubectl get service azure-vote-front
```

Result like this:

```
root@k8s-master-79E9CFFD-0:~# kubectl get service azure

NAME               CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
azure              10.0.136.182   52.224.219.190   8080:31419/TCP   10m
```

Then you can browse it with **external IP** and port, like this:

```
curl 52.224.219.190:8080
```

Also you can find the Load Balaner rules via Azure portal:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was using the wrong port to connect (31419 instead of 8080)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the IP address created for your service by getting the service information through kubectl:

```
kubectl describe services prodigy-service
```

The IP address is listed next to LoadBalancer Ingress.

Also, you can use port forwarding to access your pod:

```
kubectl port-forward <pod_name> 8880:8880
```

After that you can access Prodigy UI by `localhost:8880` in your browser.